# AngularJS / AngularFire - Pass Objects with ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have a modal *(bootstrap)* where I load Objects from the Firebase Database. Now I added a ng-Click to "select" an Object.

I want to select 8 Object and "collect" them. After I collected these 8 Objects, I want to pass them to another ng-Click. When I click on the second ng-Click these 8 *(selected)* Objects are pushed to the Database.

Do you have any idea how to archive that? Thank you!

**This is my modal:**

```
 <div class="col-md-12">
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li ng-repeat="team in teams" class="list-group-item">{{ team.allUserTeamName + " - " + team.allUserTeam }}
                            <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true" ng-init="item.isClicked = false" ng-click="selectMembers(team); item.isClicked =!item.isClicked" ng-class="{clicked : item.isClicked}"></i>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="row pad-team-selection-view">
                            <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="createGameplanWithSelectedMembers(team)">Spielplan erstellen</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**This is my Controller:**

```
app.controller('modalCreateGameplanController', ['$scope', '$timeout', '$http', '$firebaseArray', '$firebaseObject', function ($scope, $timeout, $http, $firebaseObject, $firebaseArray) {

$scope.selectUsers = 'Teilnehmer';

$scope.$on('modal', function (event, args) {

    var ref = firebase.database().ref("users");
    var teams = $firebaseObject(ref);

    teams.$loaded().then(function () {
        $scope.teams = [];
        angular.forEach(teams, function (key) {
            $scope.teams.push({
                allUserTeamName: key.firstname,
                allUserTeam: key.team
            });

            $scope.selectMembers = function (key) {
                console.log(key);
            };

            $scope.createGameplanWithSelectedMembers = function () {
                console.log(teams);
            };

        });
    });
});
}]);
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in console? Change your dependency injection order to app.controller('modalCreateGameplanController', ['$scope', '$timeout', '$http', '$firebaseArray', '$firebaseObject', function ($scope, $timeout, $http, $firebaseArray, $firebaseObject)

Comment: I can click these Objects and i get it in the console. But I want to click 8 Objects and only then "show" the "push" button with ng-show/hide.

Comment: And i need to be able to click 1 Object and when i click it again it needs to be "removed"

Comment: Put ng-if="teams.length>=8" on ng-repeat element. When you click it again, pass the item to a function and splice it off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the view use `ng-disabled` and use selected length as condition to disable the button .

```
 <div class="col-md-12">
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li ng-repeat="team in teams" class="list-group-item">{{ team.allUserTeamName + " - " + team.allUserTeam }}
                        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true" ng-init="item.isClicked = false" ng-click="selectMembers(team); item.isClicked =!item.isClicked" ng-class="{clicked : item.isClicked}"></i>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="row pad-team-selection-view">
                        <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="createGameplanWithSelectedMembers(team)" ng-disabled="selectCount==8">Spielplan erstellen</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

In the controller keep a tracker for selected items `$scope.selectCount`

```
app.controller('modalCreateGameplanController', ['$scope', '$timeout', '$http', '$firebaseArray', '$firebaseObject', function ($scope, $timeout, $http, $firebaseObject, $firebaseArray) {

$scope.selectUsers = 'Teilnehmer';

$scope.$on('modal', function (event, args) {

    var ref = firebase.database().ref("users");
    var teams = $firebaseObject(ref);

    teams.$loaded().then(function () {
       $scope.selectCount=0;
        $scope.teams = [];
        angular.forEach(teams, function (key) {
            $scope.teams.push({
                allUserTeamName: key.firstname,
                allUserTeam: key.team
            });

            $scope.selectMembers = function (key) {
                $scope.selectCount=$scope.selectCount+1;
                console.log(key);
            };

            $scope.createGameplanWithSelectedMembers = function () {
                console.log(teams);
            };

        });
    });
});
}]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Its kinda working now... The problem I have right now is this: When i click on 1 Object 8 times, the button gets enabled. And when I click more than 8 its also enabled, but it should only be enabled when 8 single Objects are selected :)